# string formatting with .format

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I am trying to find the stat and p-value using `shapiro` function
I am formatting my results using `.format` but I am not able to understand why I am getting different results for below:

```
print ('stat = {0:.2f}'.format(stat), 'p = {0:.30f}'.format (p)) 
print ('stat = {0:.2f}, p = {0:.30f}'.format (stat,p))
```

first one prints `0.000000000000000268680677283857` (this is correct)

second one prints `0.974334061145782470703125000000`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the format string of the second example.  Change the second format specification from `{0:.30f}` to `{1:.30f}`.  With this style of formatting, when the first item in the format specification is a number, it indicates which positional argument of the `format()` method to print.

For example,

```
In [81]: stat = 0.974334061145782470703125

In [82]: p = 0.000000000000000268680677283857

In [83]: print('stat = {0:.2f}, p = {1:.30f}'.format(stat, p))
stat = 0.97, p = 0.000000000000000268680677283857
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or later, you might find it more convenient to use an [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/):

```
In [93]: print(f'stat = {stat:.2f}, p = {p:0.30f}')
stat = 0.97, p = 0.000000000000000268680677283857
```

The `=` format character allows an even more concise string expression:

```
In [101]: print(f'{stat = :.2f}, {p = :0.30f}')
stat = 0.97, p = 0.000000000000000268680677283857
```